# Time frequency spectrogram in Python

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, spectrogram, time-frequency

I have some 64 channel EEG data sampled at 256Hz and I'm trying to conduct a time frequency analysis for each channel and plot a spectrogram.

The data is stored in a NumPy 3d array, where one of the dimensions has length 256, each element containing a microvolt reading over all sampled time points (total length is 1 second for each channel of data).

To be clear: my 3D array is 64*256*913 (electrode * voltages * trial). The trial is just a single trial of an experiment. So what I want to do is take a single electrode, from a single trial, and the entire 1D voltage vector and create a time-frequency spectrogram. So I want to create a spectrogram plot from data[0,:,0] for example.

For each electrode, I want a plot where the y axis is frequency, x-axis is time, and colour/intensity is power

I have tried using this in python:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import specgram
#data = np.random.rand(256)
specgram(data, NFFT=256, Fs=256)
```

This gives me something that looks like this:

[image]

Right off the bat, this looks incorrect to me because the axis ranges are incorrect

Furthermore, when I run the same code for all EEG channels, over all of my data, I end up with the exact same plot (even though I have verified that the data is different for each)

I'm pretty new to signal processing, is there somewhere that I went wrong in either how my data is laid out or how I used my function?

Comment: Could you tell something more about data? I assume that one of your axis is voltage, second is time and third one is channel - so I guess that you should take one channel, and forget about time, because period between samples is constant. For specgram you should use 1-D array or sequence, so I think that problem might be here.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I've updated the question. Basically the 3 dimensions of my 3D array are electrode * voltage * trial. I am taking a 1D array (voltage) for a single electrode in a single trial and wanting a spectrogram from it. So yes, I am plotting 1D arrays

Comment: Try something like`specgram(data, NFFT=64, noverlap=63, Fs=256)` If you have only 256 samples and you do a FFT with 256 samples, you'll have no resolution in time

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! If you post it as an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.specgram) for the `specgram` function:

> Plot a spectrogram.
>
> Call signature:
>
> specgram(x, NFFT=256, Fs=2, Fc=0, detrend=mlab.detrend_none,
>            window=mlab.window_hanning, noverlap=128,
>            cmap=None, xextent=None, pad_to=None, sides='default',
>            scale_by_freq=None, mode='default', scale='default',
>            **kwargs)
>
> Compute and plot a spectrogram of data in x. Data are split into NFFT length segments and the spectrum of each section
>   is computed. The windowing function window is applied to each segment,
>   and the amount of overlap of each segment is specified with noverlap.
>   The spectrogram is plotted as a colormap (using imshow).
>
> x: 1-D array or sequence Array or sequence containing the data

It looks like your problem is that you're not passing in 1-D data. Try:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import specgram
specgram(data.flatten(), NFFT=256, Fs=256)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm passing a 1D array. The example I posted in the question is somewhat contrived, but the commented line is 1 dimensional, and I'm extracting 1D arrays from my 3D matrix to feed into specgram (e.g. data[0,:,0] where the middle dimension contains the voltages and is the 1D array I'm passing in)